# TabBar Divider is not getting customised properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I tried to customise the dividers between the tabs of the TabBar, but it seems that the customisation isn't working properly!

Here's the link to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DNsX.jpg

**Here's my styles.xml file's code:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_purple</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/light_purple</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">

        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabsText styles -->
    <style name="ActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">

        <!-- text style -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_purple</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Action bar tab bar style -->
    <style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">

        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider_style</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">8dp</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="divider">@drawable/divider_style</item>
        <item name="dividerPadding">8dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="WalkthroughThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>

</resources>
```

**Here's my divider_style.xml file's code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="1.5dp" android:right="1.5dp" android:drawable="@color/light_purple">
        <shape android:shape="line" android:tint="@color/light_purple">
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am unable to figure out what to do here.

Please let me know what to do.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please cooperate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:drawable="@color/light_purple">
        <shape android:shape="line" android:tint="@color/light_purple">
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```